# Plotting time data with different frequencies (matplotlib, pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, time-series

I am trying to combine a Pandas time series and a number of vertical segments (markers) in the same plot. The series has the frequency of 'Q-DEC' (quarter), which in this example is inferred from the dates, but in the real problem is a part of the dataset. The markers in general are not aligned with the series and may appear anywhere, not necessarily at the end of a quarter.

My problem is that if I first plot the series and then the markers, the markers' positions are rounded up to the next end of the quarter (the upper plot). If I plot the markers first, followed by the series, the markers are in the right positions but the x ticks labels are inappropriate (the lower plot).

**Q**: How can I plot the markers at the right positions over a time series plot?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.DataFrame({0: {Timestamp('2017-03-31'): 1, 
                         Timestamp('2017-06-30'): 2, 
                         Timestamp('2017-09-30'): 3, 
                         Timestamp('2017-12-31'): 3, 
                         Timestamp('2018-03-31'): 2, 
                         Timestamp('2018-06-30'): 1}})

ax = plt.subplot(2,1,1)
data[0].plot(ax=ax,style="-mo")
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)), c='r')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 8, 10)), c='g')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 9, 20)), c='b')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)), c='k')
ax = plt.subplot(2,1,2)
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)), c='r')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 8, 10)), c='g')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 9, 20)), c='b')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)), c='k')
data[0].plot(ax=ax,style="-mo")
plt.show()
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the dates into the index as a [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.PeriodIndex.html), start with `freq="M"` to ensure the lines get drawn correctly.
Then replace the ticks with the index values set to `freq="Q-DEC"`.

```
data.set_index(pd.PeriodIndex(data.index, freq="M"), inplace=True)
ax = data[0].plot(style="-mo")

ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)), c='r')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 8, 10)), c='g')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 9, 20)), c='b')
ax.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)), c='k')
```

Now reset the ticks:

```
q_ticks = data.index.asfreq("Q-DEC")
ax.minorticks_off()
ax.set_xticks(q_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(q_ticks)
```

Output:

[image]

Note: If you don't remove the minor ticks with `minorticks_off()`, you'll get some overlap with the original monthly ticks and the new quarterly ticks.

**Update**
If you really need to get the format *exactly* as it is in your example, you'll need to do a bit of maneuvering with major and minor tick locations and formats:

```
ax.get_xaxis().set_tick_params(which='major', pad=15)

q_ticks = data.index.asfreq("Q-DEC")

# extract only the year, and only the year's first listing
major_ticklabels = pd.Series(q_ticks.strftime("%Y"))
major_ticklabels[major_ticklabels.duplicated()] = ""
ax.set_xticks(q_ticks)
ax.set_xticklabels(major_ticklabels)

# format as Q[quarter number]
minor_ticklabels = q_ticks.strftime("Q%q")
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(q_ticks, minor=True)
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(minor_ticklabels, minor=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following code can change your second subplot axis like the first subplot. Try it if you want the quarter as x-axis.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({0: {Timestamp('2017-03-31'): 1, 
                         Timestamp('2017-06-30'): 2, 
                         Timestamp('2017-09-30'): 3, 
                         Timestamp('2017-12-31'): 3, 
                         Timestamp('2018-03-31'): 2, 
                         Timestamp('2018-06-30'): 1}})

xaxis = ['Q{}'.format((pd.to_datetime(date).month-1)//3+1) for date in data.index.values]
plt.xticks(data.index.values,xaxis)

plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 7, 1)), c='r')
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 8, 10)), c='g')
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 9, 20)), c='b')
plt.axvline(pd.Timestamp(datetime.date(2017, 11, 30)), c='k')
data[0].plot(style="-mo")
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: Thank you, but your solution is very specific. If I change the frequency of the original data, I will have to rewrite the plotting (or, actually, labeling) procedure.